# How to add Kendo Menu items programatically?

Tags: kendo-ui

How do I programatically add menu items to a Kendo Menu?

```
var menu = $("#menu").data("kendoMenu");
var item1 = menu.append({text: "Option 1"});
var item2 = menu.append({text: "Option 2"}, item1);
```

This adds the items next to one another but I wish Option 2 to be a sub item of Option 1.

How do I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hop this Example could help you:

```
|Menu 1 | Menu 2 |
```

CODE

```
var menu = $("#menu1").data("kendoMenu");

menu.append({text: "OneMoreMenu",cssClass:"OneMoreMenu"});
```

Result :

```
|Menu 1 | Menu 2 | **OneMoreMenu**
```

CODE:

```
menu.append({text: "SubMenu1", cssClass:"SubMenu1"}, $('.OneMoreMenu'));
menu.append({text: "SubMenu2",cssClass:"SubMenu2"}, $('.OneMoreMenu'));
```

Result :

```
|Menu 1 | Menu 2 | **OneMoreMenu**
___________________ |SubMenu1
___________________ |SubMenu2
```

Code:

```
menu.append({text: "SubMenu2_1",cssClass:"SubMenu2_1"}, $('.SubMenu2'));
menu.append({text: "SubMenu2_2",cssClass:"SubMenu2_2"}, $('.SubMenu2'));
```

Result :

```
|Menu 1 | Menu 2 | **OneMoreMenu**
___________________ |SubMenu1
___________________ |SubMenu2___|SubMenu2_1
________________________________|SubMenu2_2
```

Comment: Yes - that is what I was after - even though I am now building my own li's and ul's based on my array so I can use a custom menu bar..   Shame though that the append doesn't return the newly created item but your technique certainly will work.  Thanks.

Comment: @Marcel you're welcome. yeah, I was wrong too. The first time I read the API ,I though that the append would return the created item. But It just return Root's Menu object.